# Too Many Files Open Error from Jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins

We are getting this error from Jenkins on startup. This occurred after a simple restart, no configuration changes were made, to my knowledge. The container has be restarted, along with the OS.

```
org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: 
IO Exception attempting to load global transforms:/[proprietary path]/jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/groovy-all-1.8.9.jar (Too many open files)

1 error

at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:246) 
at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:43) 
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:913) 
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:812) 
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81) 
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:77) 
at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:221) 
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: 
IO Exception attempting to load global transforms:/[proprietary path]/jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/groovy-all-1.8.9.jar (Too many open files)

1 error

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:302) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ProcessingUnit.completePhase(ProcessingUnit.java:143) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ProcessingUnit.gotoPhase(ProcessingUnit.java:162) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:493) 
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:302) 
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:281) 
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:731) 
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:743) 
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:723) 
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:790) 
at hudson.util.spring.BeanBuilder.parse(BeanBuilder.java:133) 
at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.createSecurityComponents(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:130) 
at hudson.security.SecurityRealm.getSecurityComponents(SecurityRealm.java:398) 
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.reset(HudsonFilter.java:134) 
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.setSecurityRealm(Jenkins.java:2053) 
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$20.run(Jenkins.java:2629) 
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:146) 
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259) 
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:902) 
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187) 
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Do You use any custom scripts where files are read? As far as I remember it's rather general JVM error rather than Jenkins itself.

Comment: I suppose You've already seen: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/I'm+getting+too+many+open+files+error ?

Comment: No, I had not see that error Opal. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the [basic solutions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/I%27m+getting+too+many+open+files+error)  suggested by Jenkins team. Does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To check the maximum limit of open files on your machine use command :

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

Increase the limit of the number of open files:

```
ulimit -n XXXX (where XXXX=new size)
```

eg: ulimit -n 8192

have a look [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/)